# How to calculate LP token worth

Tags: ethereum, solidity, decentralized-applications

I am trying to implement my own USDC liquidity pool that allows various users to deposit USDC into it to earn a fixed interest rate based on how long they park the USDC in my pool (meanwhile I will use the USDC for other things) But I am trying to work out how I can give them a ‘live’ balance on their deposit and interest earned so far. Anyone have any ideas on how I could do this ?

I am guessing that once they deposit 100 USDC then I should give them 100 LP tokens in return right ? but how to auto increment the value of those LP tokens etc has me confused

Comment: check out https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-calculate-apy-for-any-lp-token-using-javascript-in-four-simple-steps-956d8543a239